# Can postfix enforce reject_unknown_helo_hostname before permit_sasl_authenticated?

Tags: postfix, sasl, smtpd

I have a working postfix 3.5 relay where the config includes:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname,
    permit
smtpd_helo_required=yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_unknown_helo_hostname
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination
```

I see frequent attempts to authenticate in the logs:

Feb 23 16:53:02 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[30155]: connect from unknown[196.190.41.137]
Feb 23 16:53:17 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[30155]: warning: unknown[196.190.41.137]: **SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure**
Feb 23 16:53:19 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[30155]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[196.190.41.137]
Feb 23 16:53:19 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[30155]: disconnect from unknown[196.190.41.137] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/1 commands=3/4

I was hoping that `reject_unknown_helo_hostname` would reject this right away, but it seems to be allowing them to attempt SASL login instead. Although I think my saslauth is fairly secure, I would prefer if they couldn't even try.

Is there no way to get the "unknown" hostname to be rejected earlier? That would prevent 90% of the login attempts, since most of this botnet that keeps trying the same logins have unknown hostnames.

Is there something in my config that is too permissive so they can always get to the saslauth step?

In what order are the various SMTP access restrictions applied?

Edit: Wireshark shows that a recent one of these SASL Login auth failures sent this to start the session:

```
EHLO [182.150.23.17]
```

So why wasn't it rejected before this happened:

Feb 23 23:49:42 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[42557]: warning: unknown[182.150.23.17]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my own observations and tests, and a similar observation at https://mailing.postfix.users.narkive.com/AheRlxjc/blocking-access-before-sasl it seems that SMTP clients are allowed to attempt SASL auth before the server applies the various `smtpd_xxx_restrictions` rules.

From the link above:

> Appears the "smtpd_client_restrictions" are ran after the SASL is complete.
> It works as expected and prohibits the user from sending a message (even
> returns my custom REJECT reason), but tells the bot that the AUTH worked,
> so they could just try again from another IP.

So a connecting client can initiate the AUTH step, and get a response telling them whether it worked or not (which means an attacker will be know if they've successfully guessed the password!) *before* the server decides whether that connection should be rejected for whatever reason. The rejection reason might be that the client didn't send a valid hostname, or is in a blocked address ranges, or because they failed SASL auth. But those conditions and the rejection happen after the AUTH has been attempted.

This behaviour is probably a deliberate consequence of [Delayed evaluation of SMTP access restriction lists](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing). I'll experiment with whether using `smtpd_delay_reject=no` changes the behaviour, although that is documented as causing problems for some clients. It might be that I don't care about those clients, because buggy smtp clients are probably spambots anyway.

The suggestion at the link above is to use [postscreen](https://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html) to filter out spammers instead. I guess I'll look into that too.

Edit: Using `smtpd_delay_reject=no` does seem to give the desired results. Clients with invalid hostnames are now rejected immediately, before they can even negotiate a TLS session or attempt to authenticate. My logs now show:

postfix/smtpd[64594]: NOQUEUE: reject: CONNECT from unknown[45.88.90.174]: 450 4.7.25 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [45.88.90.174]; proto=SMTP

I suspect the reason I wasn't seeing such errors in the past is that the spambots attempting to brute force my SASL auth were dropping the connection as soon as failing to login, so they didn't stick around long enough to get a rejection. That seems consistent with the logs shown in the question above, where the connection drops after they fail to login:

Feb 23 16:53:19 m.example.com postfix/smtpd[30155]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[196.190.41.137]

So the reason I wasn't seeing the expected `reject` logs based on invalid/unknown client hostnames is because the clients are bad actors who are not even waiting long enough to get rejected.